# Textmate - SVNMate

Tags: textmatebundles, textmate-1.5

I've installed the latest version of SVNMate but the overlay icons are not showing on my files drawer. I can perform SVN actions through the bundle though.

Has anyone else encountered this before and resolved it?

I'm using TextMate 1.5.10(1631) demo version on Mac 10.6.7.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I removed all plugins from ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/PlugIns

Downloaded the plugin from [here](http://ciaranwal.sh/projectplus) and it worked.

I was super frustrated too and tried many times, but finally got it to work.